# $B_{16}$ Meaning on Math Clock

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

In my office, there's a clock that replaces the usual numbers on an analog clock with equivalent mathematical expressions. For instance, in place of the number "$10$," the clock has $\log_2(1024)$. Most of these expressions are simple to figure out, like in this case. However, in place of "$11$," the clock has written $B_{16}$. I might be missing something super obvious, but I don't know what this means.

Does anyone know what $B_{16}$ refers to? Presumably it is the $16$th number in some famous sequence, probably named after someone with last name starting with "B," and is equal to $11$, but it isn't Bernoulli numbers (where $B_{16}\approx -7$) nor Bell numbers (some massive quantity). If you Google "mathematical clock," this exact clock is one of the first that shows up, in case someone wants to see it directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The base $16$ digit $B$ represents $11$.

Comment: Thanks much! It would have taken me forever to guess this. I'll accept this once the 10 minutes expires.

Comment: You mean the $\log_2(1024)$ minutes, I suppose.